# Creating an Array based on range from existing array

Tags: arrays, c++11

Say I have a `std::array`

```
std::array<int,8> foo = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

Now Is it possible to create a new array from an existing array using a range say from index to 2 till 5. So my new array will have items {3,4,5,6}. 
I am aware that I could accomplish this using the manual for loop copy mechanism but I wanted to know if there was a faster way of doing that

Comment: Try: [std::copy](http://zh.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: BTW, do you want a copy or a "view" of the original data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting some easy syntax (like Python, Matlab or Fortran), no.

As @Sphinx said you can use copy.

```
std::array<int,8> foo = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
std::array<int,3> foo2; 
std::copy(&foo[2], &foo[5], foo2.begin()); 
// or std::copy(foo.begin() + 2, foo.begin() + 5, foo2.begin());
```

but take into account that `std::array` sizes are compile time constants.
So you may need `std::vector<int>` if you want make the range size variable.